# Styling TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-styles, graphs

I have created a TikZ graph, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=2cm]

  \node (6) {6};
  \node (7) [right of = 6] {7};
  \node (10) [below = 7, right of = 6] {10};
  \node (11) [right of=10] {11};
  \node (12) [right of=11] {12};

  \path
    (7)  edge node [above] {$b$} (6)
         edge node [right] {$\tau$} (10)
         edge node [above right] {$a$} (11)
    (10) edge node [above] {$a$} (11)
    (11) edge node [above] {$a$} (12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

How can I get my TikZ graph to visually look like the one below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The lower picture has been done with the package `xy`. You could ask the author for its code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing which `tikz` libraries you are using.  With `positioning`, writing just `\node (10) [below of= 7] {10};` gives a layout closer to the type of diagram wanted.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks! I will look into `xy`.

Comment: @NiekHaarman This is quite old. Better look in `tikz-cd`. If I would've reccomended `xy`, I would have written my answer as such.

Comment: @LaRiFari Ah, I hadn't noticed the answer was yours as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) or any other package for commutative diagrams.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl} % [a4paper,11pt] are both default here
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % loads TikZ as well. Can be followed by any TikZ library

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
                  & 0  \arrow{r}{a}       \arrow{d}{\tau}                            & 1  \arrow{d}{\tau}                                                    & \\
2 \arrow{d}{\tau} & 3  \arrow{l}[swap]{b} \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{d}{\tau}               & 4  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow[bend left]{d}{\tau}                            & 5  \arrow[bend left]{d}{\tau} \\
6                 & 7  \arrow{l}[swap]{b} \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{d}{\tau} \arrow{dr}{a} & 8  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow[bend left]{d}{\tau} \arrow[bend left]{u}{\tau} & 9  \arrow[bend left]{d}{\tau} \arrow[bend left]{u}{\tau} \\
                  & 10 \arrow{r}{a}                                                  & 11 \arrow{r}{a} \arrow[bend left]{u}{\tau}                            & 12 \arrow[bend left]{u}{\tau} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to get exactly your picture, you may vary some values in the line `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=...ex, column sep=...em]` and for the bent arrows `\arrow[bend left=...]{u}{\tau}`.

---

The one arrow you added in your first attempt would be `& 7 \arrow{dr}{a} &` here.

Comment: Thanks! Since I actually only needed the reduced graph, I have minimized it to `& 6 & 7 \arrow{l}[swap]{b} \arrow{d}{\tau} \arrow{dr}{a} & \\ &   & 10  \arrow{r}{a} & 11 \arrow{r}{a} & 12`

Comment: @NiekHaarman You are welcome.